# How to build Visual C++ project using gradle?

Tags: visual-c++, build.gradle

How to build Visual C++ project  using gradle?
We have used MSBuild plugin but it failed.Our project type is vcxproj.

Comment: why did it fail ? what error did you get ?

Comment: The project type is something the visual studio IDE uses to configure its build. For gradle you'll need to start from scratch to specify the build process, if that plugin doesn't work as expected.

Comment: And it won't, since it only [supports C#](https://github.com/Ullink/gradle-msbuild-plugin) as of now.